# Serialize JSONModel - How to convert custom object to JSON in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

How to serialize a custom object with JSONModel ?

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString<Optional> * tag_post_type;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString<Optional> * tag_users_type;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray<Optional> * tags;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray<TagMediaModel*>* tag_posts;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray<TagLocationModel*>* locations;
```

I try to create a JSON file out of my custom Object with the JSONModel framework for iOS. I get the Error:

```
EXCEPTION: Invalid type in JSON write (TagMediaModel)
```

When I call toJSONString Method, I got this issue.

```
[tagAutomaticModel toJSONString];
```

This is the model data:

```
 locations =     (
    "<TagLocationModel> \n   [id]: 780307344\n   [name]: Hotel Central Park, india\n</TagLocationModel>",
    "<TagLocationModel> \n   [id]: 463004401\n   [name]: Miraj Cinema new year\n</TagLocationModel>",
    "<TagLocationModel> \n   [id]: 246187965\n   [name]: Surya Treasure Island asia\n</TagLocationModel>",
);
"tag_posts" =     (
    "<TagMediaModel> \n   [media_code]: BS0tQeFhU_Z\n   [media_id]: 1492016420475981785\n   [media_url]: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/17881459_...\n   [media_type]: I\n</TagMediaModel>"
);
```

Comment: Can you please share which kind of data you stored in it?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh check now. I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

`@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray<TagMediaModel>* tag_posts;`

made few change as above, just removed the star in TagMediaModel.

Comment: if the above suggestion works fine then accept this answer. @Shakti

Answer (score 0):

The angle brackets after NSMutableArray contain a protocol. As @R.Mohan said, you need to `remove` `* pointer` and use `without pointer`.

1. The protocol must be in place. So add `@protocol tag_posts` and `@protocol locations` at top in respective class.
2. `EXCEPTION: Invalid type in JSON write (TagMediaModel)` I guess you are converting json to your custom class one or more times. Do it only once. It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes. Got the issue. I converted json to model twice. Thanks a lot!